# Как использовать php в html форме?

Tags: php, html

У меня есть аккаунт в unitpay, я хочу подключить у них оплату. Но нужно создавать уникальную подпись в форме html. Как это сделать?

```
<form action="https://unitpay.money/pay/243161-58f63">
<input type="text" name="account" value="test">
<input type="text" name="sum" value="50">
<input type="hidden" name="desc" value="Описание платежа">
<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Оплатить">
<input type="hidden" name="signature" value="<?php не знаю что тут ?>"
</form>
```

Функция откуда берётся подпись

```
function getSignature($method, array $params, $secretKey)
{
    ksort($params);
    unset($params['sign']);
    unset($params['signature']);
    array_push($params, $secretKey);
    array_unshift($params, $method);
    return hash('sha256', join('{up}', $params));
}?>
```

Comment: `value="<?php echo getSignature($method, array $params, $secretKey) ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо знать метод платежа, параметры и Ваш секретный ключ и затем вставить все это в `html` вот так:

```
<form action="https://unitpay.money/pay/243161-58f63">
<input type="text" name="account" value="test">
<input type="text" name="sum" value="50">
<input type="hidden" name="desc" value="Описание платежа">
<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Оплатить">
<input type="hidden" name="signature" value="<?php echo getSignature(Здесь метод платежа, здесь параметры платежа, здесь Ваш секретный ключ); ?>"
</form>
```

Но если Вы не знаете `php`, то имейте ввиду как пишутся строки в функцию - в кавычках, а переменные без

```
getSignature('payments', 'sum: 50', 'TTGJDKDKLA6786JHKJHKJBND');
```

если переменная, то

```
$method = 'payments';

$params = 'sum: 50';

$secret = 'TTGJDKDKLA6786JHKJHKJBND';

getSignature($method, $params, $secret);
```